# googleapi: Error 403: Rate Limit Exceeded, rateLimitExceeded

Tags: google-drive-api

I understand the error is part of API quota limits but i have not been able to find a way to;

1. Track usage
2. Know when API limit resets

I have ran through information in stackoverflow and google dev portals still can't find any clear guidance.

Can any one provide clear guidance if available?

Answer (score 1):

From this [article](https://cloudsolutions.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CKB/pages/113377281/Reaching+or+exceeding+Google+API+quotas):

If you are experiencing errors such as "User Rate Limit Exceeded", you are reaching or exceeding your destination Google Gmail, Calendar or Drive account's API quota. These quotas **usually reset after a 24 hour period**, and migrations can be rerun / continued.

You can apply the suggestion actions from the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded):

- [Batch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) the requests.
- Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) to retry the request.

Comment: Was looking for a way to track usage of requests, maybe setup an alert when close to limit or when limit reset. Figure out yesterday reset clock is on GMT even though organization time zone is PST.

Comment: That's great. Yes, you can set a notification alert whenever you will hit the quota limit.